# Bonito/Bonita: only for *things*? (Spanish from Spain, please)

Tags: uso-de-palabras, españa, sinónimos

My question is only about Spanish from Spain.

I read on the Internet that 'Bonito/Bonita' was only for things, not for men or women?

Is it correct or weird to use 'un hombre bonito'? (I know it's considered correct in American Spanish)

The RAE says that it means to have beautifulness (belleza), nothing in their definition could imply that's not correct. I just want to be sure. Speakers would probably prefer to use guapo/guapa and to keep the use of bonito for things, but is a word misuse?

Comment: One of your assumptions is incorrect.  In Mexico, at least, *bonita* would be fine for a female but *bonito* would only be okay for a boy.  It would be a complicated word to use for a grown man -- in general it would be best to avoid it for a grown man.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While it is correct, we favor "guapo/guapa" for people, unless you are talking about babies. It could still be okay to address as "bonita" to a young girl, but if would sound awkward for men.

So, it is not just used for things, but when addressing people and almos always "people of short age".

You can definitely say

> Bonito! Eres el bebé más bonito que he visto en mi vida

Meaning that he is a cute baby. Not just "good looking" but overall "beautiful".

It would indeed weird to say that a man is "bonito" instead of "guapo" or "atractivo". It would be like calling a man "beautiful" instead of handsome. Technically you could do it, but you are going to favor "handsome" for a number of connotations on both words.

Comment: bonito literally means cute, you can call girls cute, but i think you should think twice before calling a man cute